# Counting number of characters in TextBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, character, keypress

I have a `TextBox` by which if the user enters more than 10 characters it displays a `MsgBox`. That part works :D

The problem is the message also displays if the `TextBox` is empty and the user types the first character. I think thats because `Null` is seen as something greater than 10? but I'm not sure.

A) What is going on?

B) How can I fix this?

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
    If TextBox3.Text.Length >= 10 Then
        MsgBox("WARNING")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `TextBox3.Text`? And no, `null` or `Nothing` don't have a length so it's also not equals or greater than 10. But a `TextBox.Text` never returns `null` or `Nothing` anyway, even if you assign `Nothing` the property will return `String.Empty` which length is 0.

Comment: Try using `TextBox3_TextChanged` instead.

Comment: The `KeyPress` event happens _before_ the text is put into the box.

Comment: Are you sure you've labeled your TextBoxes correctly? That shouldn't show a MsgBox unless the length is >=10

Comment: You should put a breakpoint and see what is the content of the .Text property and the Length property.

Comment: `the message also displays if the TextBox is empty and the user types the first character` that code will not result in that problem.  You likely have some other code somewhere throwing up some other messagebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. By using trim, white space characters is ignored. For an example, if the user only entered 10 [Spacebar] keys it will trim it out.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
If TextBox3.Text.Trim().Length() >= 10 Then
    MsgBox("WARNING")
End If
End Sub
```